# Subjects lectured per week

Tags: teaching, working-time, lecturer

I am currently lecturing at a private tertiary education college where I am obliged to lecture, on average, 12 distinct subjects per year at both diploma and degree level. I lecture 6 to 8 subjects per week or around 4 or 5 unique subjects per day across all graduate levels (first, second and third year students). Some of these classes are repeated identically up to 7 times each week for 7 different groups of students for around 30 to 35 lecturing hours per week.

I am currently feeling a little overwhelmed by the workload. Is this normal for a private education institution?

Comment: It sounds like your workload would be reduced *a lot* if you could cut down on the number of "repeat" lectures. Perhaps you and the college can get together and arrange next year's timetabling so that you're only repeating each lecture a few times.

Comment: Is there a practical difference between "college" and "tertiary education" in this context? Wikipedia suggests that the broad definition of "tertiary" includes lots of other educational facilities (trade school, technical institutes, etc), but this just sounds like a typical college.

Comment: It is a technical college which caters mostly to diploma students but there is a small Bsc component of around 15 students. I lecture them all - 1st , 2nd and 3rd year diploma, as well as 1st, 2nd and 3rd year degree.

Answer (score 12):

I have never heard of an undergraduate institution inflicting this level of lecturing on a professor.  Perhaps it happens at vocational or associates degree schools, where, e.g., you might be teaching a whole bunch of sections of "database entry" or "machine operation" or something like that?

For my colleagues at institutions offering 4-year degrees, the normal range is:

- 1-2 classes in a semester at a research-centric institution, where the professor is expected to also be supervising Ph.D. students
- 3-4 classes in a semester at a teaching-centric institution, where that is expected to be the primary focus.

Depending on the format of the classes, then, that is likely to mean somewhere between 2 and 20 hours of lecturing per week, which is still far less than what you report.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds as if it would be the equivalent of a 6:6 (six courses per semester; two semesters a year) teaching load. It also sounds like you can share course-preps between some classes, which lessens the burden a little bit.

A 6:6 load is unheard of at American research universities and liberal arts colleges or any place where you are expected to also do research and service work (university committees, student mentoring, etc.). In these places, 2:1, 2:2, 2:3, or 3:2 are the norm.

That being said, even a 5:5 teaching load is not unheard of at community colleges and some lower-tier state colleges, especially for the non tenure-track instructional staff.

I've never heard of a full-time 6:6 teaching load at a college or university in the United States -- except for adjunct faculty, who often have to do this because they are only paid a piddling ($2~3000) per class. Usually, those 12 classes are spread between different institutions in the same region.

Comment: I wrote the course material for some of the subjects that I lecture, which means that setting assessments is the only preparation work required for them. The other subjects however, do require preparation for each class, which, under this lecturing workload, often means evenings and weekends.

Answer (score 2):

While I believe @jakebeal's answer is quite common in the US and UK, in Asia you get pushed a little harder...but still not as hard as they are pushing you. Here it is common that full time undergraduate lecturers are expected to be in the classroom 16-20 hours per week. I've known cases of lecturers who were pressured into lecturing 28 hours per week, but they were paid extra for those extra hours.

Since your question is not about about the financial aspects of but rather how much one can do, here they traditionally try to get you to teach only 3 unique subjects per week which can be 6 per year (or less). It is common that classes get repeated - that is, you teach the exact same material to multiple, separate groups of students. Combining the student groups into larger classes is not always an option.

12 distinct subjects per year / 6 to 8 unique subjects per week (you also described 4-5 subjects per day)... this is too much for most people (anyone?) to handle while delivering a reasonable quality. If they have you switching subjects this often, it implies that they are more concerned with quantity than quality.

It would help to know what country/area you are in. Again, standards in the US are not the same as Europe which is different from Asia.

Comment: I am in South Africa at a private educational institution which has a particularly keen eye on its bottom line. The quantity versus quality issue is at the heart of the matter for me and this is why I asked the question - to find out if there are similar practices internationally.

Comment: @Vertigo There are similar places but your case is quite extreme.